# Pandas loc() function

Tags: pandas

I am trying to slice item from CSV here is example  [enter image description here][1]

```
df1 = pandas.read_csv("supermarkets.csv")
df1

    ID  Address City    State   Country Name    Employees
0   1   3666 21st St    San Francisco   CA 94114    USA Madeira 8
1   2   735 Dolores St  San Francisco   CA 94119    USA Bready Shop 15
2   3   332 Hill St San Francisco   California 94114    USA Super River 25
3   4   3995 23rd St    San Francisco   CA 94114    USA Ben's Shop  10
4   5   1056 Sanchez St San Francisco   California  USA Sanchez 12
5   6   551 Alvarado St San Francisco   CA 94114    USA Richvalley  20

df2 = df1.loc["735 Dolores St":"332 Hill St","City":"Country"]
df2
```

In output I am only getting this output

```
    City    State   Country
```

How do I correct?

Comment: Did this help or need more support?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc) `.loc[]` can access a group of rows and columns by **label(s)** or a **boolean array**.

You cannot directly select using the values in the Series.

In your example `df1.loc["735 Dolores St":"332 Hill St","City":"Country"]` you are getting an empty selection because only `"City":"Country"` is a valid accessor.

`"735 Dolores St":"332 Hill St"` will return an empty row selection as they are not labels on the index.

You can try selecting by index with `.iloc[[1,2], "City":"Country"]` if you want specific rows.

Answer (score 0):

`df.loc` is primarily label based and commonly slices the rows using an index. In this case, you can use the numeric index or set address as index

```
 print(df)



  ID    Address   City           State      Country         Name             Employees
0   1    3666 21st  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA           Madeira              8
1   2  735 Dolores  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA           Bready Shop         15
2   3     332 Hill  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA           Super River         25

df2=df.loc[1:2,'City':'Country']
print(df2)

             City     State Country
1  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA
2  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA
```

Or

```
df2=df.set_index('Address').loc['735 Dolores':'332 Hill','City':'Country']
print(df2)


                  City     State      Country
Address                                     
735 Dolores  San Francisco  CA 94114     USA
332 Hill     San Francisco  CA 94114     USA
```